# Add to Existing Model based on a POCO with need to add to List<T>

Tags: c#, list, poco

I have a poco model that looks like this:

```
public int Id {get; set;
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
public int? GenderTypeId { get; set; }
public List<FindPersonResultsViewModel> findPersonResultsViewModel { get; set; }
```

The List FindPersonResultsViewModel contains

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

At first on a Post I have the following data

```
public IActionResult FindPerson (FindPersonViewModel findPersonViewModel)

    Id : 4432
    EmailAddress:  "johnsmith@test.com"
    findPersonResultsViewModel  :  null
```

So what I want to do is hydrate this list view model with some dummy data ( I will add real data later...

Seems like I'm having trouble with knowing how to do this, new up a list of this ?

```
findPersonViewModel.findPersonResultsViewModel.Add({  ??

List<FindPersonResultsViewModel> findPersonResultsViewModel = 
    new List<FindPersonResultsViewModel>();   
// How to add data , especially to that model that contains the list   findPersonViewModel  ??
```

Comment: Do you just want to add data to the list when creating?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is add some data to the null list on your object, you can do something like this:

```
var results = new List<FindPersonResultsViewModel>();
results.Add(new FindPersonResultsViewModel(){ ... all my properties ..});
findPersonViewModel.findPersonResultsViewModel = results;
```