# Adding data to an existing model with real data to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, asp.net-core, viewmodel

I have a previous question that shows how my models look and it was adding FAKE data.  [Add to Existing Model based on a POCO with need to add to List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534700/add-to-existing-model-based-on-a-poco-with-need-to-add-to-listt/)

Now I am wanting to add REAL data and i'm wondering how to do this.  Should or need I loop over the `result` ??

```
public IActionResult FindPerson (FindPersonViewModel findPersonViewModel)
{
    var firstName = findPersonViewModel.FirstName;
    var middleName = findPersonViewModel.MiddleName;
    var lastName = findPersonViewModel.LastName;
    var emailAddress = findPersonViewModel.EmailAddress;
    var genderTypeId = findPersonViewModel.GenderTypeId;


    // GET REAL DATA 
    using (AzEdsIdentityContext context = new AzEdsIdentityContext(AzEdsIdentityContext.Options))
    {
         var result = context.FindPerson(firstName, lastName, genderTypeId);

         // for loop on the result to hydrate new List<FindPersonResultsViewModel>()  ?         

    }


   // Note:  here is exactly how I hydrated the model with fake data

   findPersonViewModel.findPersonResultsViewModel = new List<FindPersonResultsViewModel>()
                { new FindPersonResultsViewModel { AZEDID = 33423432, PersonID = 3534454, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Williamson", MiddleName = "K", ExistInContactManager = false, ActionType = true, ContactType = "Principal", DOB = "5/1/1985", PhysicalAddress = "123 main st. mesa, az.", PreferredEmail = "john@aol.com", PreferredPhone = "602-393-4443"},
                  new FindPersonResultsViewModel { AZEDID = 33423432, PersonID = 3534454, FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Williamson", MiddleName = "K", ExistInContactManager = false, ActionType = true, ContactType = "Principal", DOB = "5/1/1985", PhysicalAddress = "123 main st. mesa, az.", PreferredEmail = "john@aol.com", PreferredPhone = "602-393-4443"},
   };


}
```

Comment: Just set the collection property to the result you obtain fro the context. If the models do not match then you'll need a [Select projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251976/what-is-a-projection-in-linq-as-in-select).

Comment: @Jasen  I'm not sure it is going to match up,  can you show me an example?

Comment: What exactly are you getting out of `context.FindPerson()`? How does that differ from your "fake" data?

Comment: A lot of the same fields,  so would I do a foreach loop and create a new List ?

Comment: You do not need to loop through the result. See the linked answer.

Comment: You'll do a projection `context.FindPerson().Select(p => new PersonViewModel { Name = p.Name, Email = p.AnotherNamedEmailField, ...})`

Comment: I'm wondering where the results are going to be at  `context.FindPerson(firstName, lastName, genderTypeId).Select(p => new FindPersonResultsViewModel { FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName });`

Comment: You'd assign it to your `result` variable.

Comment: I need to be able to add List of results from the query to this model   `findPersonViewModel`

Comment: I know that I had that result variable there,  but really I want to place into the findPersonViewModel  (as this model has a List<FindPersonResultsViewModel>

Comment: @Jasen   - I'm closer  but this is still not resolving `findPersonViewModel.findPersonResultsViewModel = context.FindPerson(firstName, lastName, genderTypeId).Select(p => new FindPersonResultsViewModel { FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName });`

Comment: IEnumerable vs. a List  , can't do implicit

Comment: Oh,  .ToList()     works   thx @Jasen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Person model

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And you obtain the result from your context

```
List<Person> result = context.getPersons();
```

You need a collection of a different but similar type, so you use a projection

```
List<PersonViewModel> result =
    context.getPersons()
           .Select(p => new FindPersonResultsViewModel
                            {
                                Name = p.Name,
                                Email = p.Email
                            }).ToList();
```

Then assign the collection property to another model

```
var model = new ResultViewModel
                {
                    ...
                    findPersonResultsViewModel = result
                };
```

If you're getting back IEnumerable, do `.ToList()` to get the `List<T>`.